# Heun's method maximum error

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

It can be easily found on the Internet many proof that Heun's method error has order $O(h^3)$. However, I have been searching for a formula for the maximum error but I haven't found any. The closest I got was on this page

https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~math211/Laboratories/08/Heuns/

But I do not understand where he gets the values for $\tau$. I deduced the following formula, based on the truncation term.

$E = (\frac{1}{4}||f'||_{\infty} ||y^2||_{\infty} - \frac{1}{12}||y^3||_{\infty})h^3$

where $||.||_{\infty}$ denotes the maximum value on the interval. Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct error in your formula is that

- first, the application of the triangle inequality never results in a norm difference in the upper bound.
- and second, the upper indices should be derivative orders, not powers, thus written as either $y^{(2)}$ or $y''$ etc.

Indeed, as reconstructed below, you get a correct bound with the same terms, but in a sum, not a difference.

---

To simplify the calculus, consider an autonomous system $y'=f(y)$, as you can always have $f_1(y)=1$ to get a time variable. The discretization error of Heun's explicit trapezoidal method is, in the form you use, given by
\begin{align}
E(h)&=y(x+h)-y(x)-\frac{h}2\Bigl(f(y(x))+f\bigl(y(x)+hf(y(x))\bigr)\Bigr)
\\
&=\left[y(x+h)-y(x)-\frac{h}2\bigl(f(y(x))+f(y(x+h))\bigr)\right]+\frac{h}2\left[f\bigl(y(x)+hf(y(x))\bigr)-f(y(x+h))\right].
\end{align}

For the first term use the error formula of the trapezoidal quadrature method for the function $g(x)=y_i'(x)=f_i(y(x))$. It gives
$$
\frac{h}2(g(x)+g(x+h))-\int_x^{x+h}g(s)ds=-\frac{h^3}{12}g''(x+\theta_i h)
$$
so that the first term has the error bound
\begin{align}
\left\|y(x+h)-y(x)-\frac h2(f(y(x+h))+f(y(x)))\right\|
&\le\frac{h^3}{12}\sup_{\theta\in[0,1]}\|y'''(x+\theta h)\|
\end{align}
For the second term we get using a Lipschitz constant $L_f=\|f'\|_\infty$
\begin{align}
\|f(y(x)+hf(y(x)))−f(y(x+h))\|&\le L_f\|y(x)+hy'(x)−y(x+h)\|
\\&\le L_f\int_x^{x+h}(x+h-s)\|y''(s)\|
\\&\le L_f \frac{h^2}2\sup_{\theta\in[0,1]}\|y''(x+\theta h)\|
\end{align}

In combination this gives for the error of the explicit method
\begin{align}
\|E(h)\|
&\le \frac{h^3}{12}·\|y'''\|_\infty+\frac{h^3}{4}·\|f'\|_\infty·\|y''\|_\infty
\end{align}

This is the most optimistic outcome you could expect from the error formula of the linked article.

Comment: Can we conclude from this error sum that if $y'''(x)=0$, then the error is zero?

Comment: Can we conclude from this error sum that if $y'''(x)=0$, then the error is zero?

Comment: Yes and no. It is only true if this derivative is zero for any exact solution. And then there remains the second term that has the second derivative. So if every exact solution is linear, the error will be zero, apart from floating-point errors. In general the truncation error causes the numerical solution to traverse the family of exact solutions, so each truncation error is based on a different exact solution. For a global error bound one would need to express $y''$ and $y'''$ in terms of derivatives of $f$ and use a bound of these expressions in some neighborhood of the exact IVP solution.

Comment: Thank you. Does Heun not give the exact solution for quadratic? Which have everywhere zero third derivative? Aren't all functions with everywhere zero third derivative quadratics? Or is there some technical issue I am not getting?

Comment: You mean Heun reduced to the trapezoidal quadrature method? Yes, that is exact for a linear input function. With a full ODE one gets for instance $y'=\frac{2y}{1+t}$ that has quadratic solutions $y(t)=C(1+t)^2$. I'm not sure if Heun would be exact here. Note that the above argument is about autonomous DE, which both these examples are not. There one would have to try $y'=2\sqrt{y}$ with $y(0)>0$.

Comment: Very interesting. I see that e.g. with $y(0)=1$, we have $y(t)=(1+t)^2$, then with $y'=2y/(1+t)$, and $h=1$ I find $y_1=3.5\neq y(1)$. 

Of course if I change the ode to $y'=2(1+t)$, which has the same solution, but has no need for a predictor, then I get $y_1=y(1)$. 

This is a good lesson for me, thank you for your time.

Comment: Am I right that the first expression should be (note the red chars) \begin{align}
E(h)&=y(x+h)-y(x)-\frac{h}2\Bigl(f(y(x))+f\bigl(y(x)+hf(y(x))\bigr)\Bigr)
\\
&=\left[y(x+h)-y(x)-\frac {\color{red}h}{2}\bigl(f(y(x))+f(y(x+h))\bigr)\right]\color{red}-\frac{h}2\left[f\bigl(y(x)+hf(y(x))\bigr)-f(y(x+h))\right].
\end{align}

Comment: @VIVID : Yes, thank you.